# Creating a factory object with multiple association

Tags: unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

I have 3 model

```
class Account 
end

class AccountType
end

class Lookup
end
```

I want to create a factory as

```
  1  factory :account_test, class: 'Account' do 
  2      sequence(:name) {|i| "Account #{i}"}
  3      association :account_type, factory: :account_type_with_data
  4      association :lookup, factory: :lookup_value_with_account_type
  5      active "1"
  6    end
  7  
  8  factory :lookup_value_with_account_type, class: 'Lookup' do
  9    association :account_type, ????????
  10 end
```

In case of second factory I want to use the value of account_type generated in line 3 in the factory for line 9. How can I do so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to look into the `transient` block and the `after` callback.

I do something similar in this factory where I take attributes of a recently created `event_session` and use them to create and event session post.

Hope this helps or maybe points you in the right direction.

```
# Usage Notes:
# Use create(:event_session, create_post: true) to create associated event session post using event_session's title and body.

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :event_session do

    transient do
      event_session nil
      create_post false
    end

    name {Faker::Commerce.product_name}
    description { Faker::Company.catch_phrase + '. ' + Faker::Company.catch_phrase }
    start_date_time { Time.now }
    end_date_time { Time.now + 1.hours }
    track_name { Faker::Company.catch_phrase }
    session_type { Faker::Commerce.product_name }
    room_name { Faker::Commerce.product_name }
    sponsor { create(:sponsor) }
    display_rank [*1..100].sample
    event { create(:event, :random)}
    sequence(:client_id) { |n| "client_id_#{n}" }

    after(:create) do |event_session, evaluator|
      create(:post, event_session: event_session, title: evaluator.name, body: evaluator.description) if @overrides.present? && @overrides[:create_post] || evaluator == true
    end

  end
end
```